# No config files for mysql / mariadb-server

Tags: apt, 18.04, mysql, mariadb

I have a problem on one server running Ubuntu 18.04. I have no idea, but the server does not generate config files for the mariadb-server. The /etc/mysql directory does not exist after the installation of the server.

I also tried to reinstall the server. Same. 
I also tried this:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" install --reinstall mariadb-server
```

Still there is no /etc/mysql directory. What can I do to get it?